# Well Pressure Greater than 100 psi to pressure tank

Tags: plumbing

My signature 2000 pressure tank has a collapsed bladder and the pump runs with all water usage. Two days ago the pressure suddenly increased a lot and now the pressure switch gauge is pegged @ 100psi (normally 60)and the pressure switch isn't cutting in with any water usage. It's like there is no need for the tank.  I'm worried about the tank itself being at or OVER 100psi. Any ideas?

Comment: wait for it to go boom maybe? ... it is unclear what you are asking? ... you have not said what you have done to resolve your problem. ... are you actually going to do nothing until somebody answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

Must be a faulty pressure switch.  You can try loosening the main spring tension in there see if that helps.  You can turn off the breaker and get that pressure down a bit and try to figure out why the well pump does not turn off.  Pressure is high because the well pump is not cutting out at 60 psi anymore for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this happen, turned out the pipe going to pressure switch was completely blocked with dirt. Cleaned it out and it back to working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When the bladder in a pressure tank fails this can cause the pump to cycle rapidly like a machine gun this is very hard on the pump and switch. Rapid cycling can cause the contacts in the switch to become "sticky" because of all the arcing. Add some air to the tank it may help until you can replace it. I have added air to tanks with blown bladders and as long as the tank is not emptied and the air escapes this can reduce the damage to the pump and switch from rapid cycling. You need to replace the bladder or tank depending on model before more damage to the system.